# Different major tick format in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'd like to make regular tick format HH:mm and major ones (on day begin) - MMM D.

My codepen https://codepen.io/zzmaster/pen/OvNdLe

```
var options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
                unit: 'hour',
                unitStepSize: 1,
                displayFormats: {
                    'hour': 'HH:mm',
                    'day': 'MMM D HH:mm'
                },
            },
            ticks:{
                maxTicksLimit: 10,
                major: {
                    unit: 'day',
                    fontColor: 'red',
                    unitStepSize: 1,
                    displayFormats: {
                        'day': 'MMM D HH:mm',
                        'hour': 'MMM D'
                    },
                },
            },
        }],

        yAxes: [{
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: 'Loading'
            },
        }],
    },

};
```

Looks like displayFormats ignored for major ticks? And I generally don't understand what is the reason of using multiple entries under displayFormats, on which conditions will be used hour or day format? I see no difference in output ticks..

Answer (score 1):

```
ticks: {
    major: {
        fontSize: 14,
        fontStyle: "bold"
    },
    callback: function(value, index, values) {
        if(values[index] !== undefined)
        {
            if(values[index].major==true)
            {
                return moment(values[index].value).format('DD/MM');
            }
            else
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```