# Is there a way to change the font of major ticks in Chart.js 3.x.x?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have seen some older questions ([such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49313954/different-major-tick-format-in-chart-js)) that show how to modify major tick font style in Chart.js 2.x.x with the `options.scales.xAxes.ticks.major.fontStyle` property. However, `fontStyle` does not appear to be a valid property in 3.x.x. I thought maybe the issue was that 3.x.x uses `font` objects, so I tried adding one of those within `options.scales.x.ticks.major`, like this:

```js
           ticks: {
                major: {
                    enabled: true,
                    font: {
                       weight: 'bold'
                    },
                },
```

However, that had no effect. I next tried to use a callback function within `options.scales.x.ticks`, but could not figure out any way to access the format of the tick in the callback function (though I did at least add "--" to the major ticks as a temporary way to set them apart):

```js
                callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                    if(ticks[index].major == true) {
                        return "--" + value + "--";
                    }
                    else {
                        return value;
                    }
                }
```

Finally, I saw the "[scriptable options](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/general/options.html#scriptable-options)" answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932374/chartjs-only-show-large-font-size-for-a-specific-tick), so I tried to add a script in `options.scales.x.ticks.font.weight` as shown in the final configuration below. I am sure that this is the correct way to do it, but I must just have some problem with my code.  Can anyone figure it out?  Here's the full configuration:

```js
const bgPlugin = {
    id: 'customBgColor',
    beforeDraw: (chart, args, options) => {
        const {ctx} = chart;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
        ctx.fillStyle = options.color || "#f5f3ef";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);
        ctx.restore();
    }
};

var data = {
  datasets: [{/* formatted data is inserted here by the PHP parent script */}]};
  
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    parsing: false,
    animation: false,
    plugins: {
      decimation: {
        enabled: true,
        algorithm: 'min-max',
      },
      customBgColor: {
          color: "#f5f3ef",
      }
    },
    scales: {
        x: {
            type: 'time',
            adapters: {
                date: {
                    zone: "America/Los_Angeles",
                },
            },
            ticks: {
                major: {
                    enabled: true,
                },
                font: {
                    weight: (c) => {
                        if(c.major == true) {
                            return 'bold';
                        }
                        else {
                            return 'normal';
                        }
                    }
                },
            }, 
        },
    },
  },
  plugins: [bgPlugin],
};
```

Here are two examples of charts produced by the above configuration over different time ranges, you can see the major ticks are '5 PM', etc., in first chart, and are the dates in the second chart, but they are not bold:
[image: a chart of temperatures for three sensors]

[image: a similar chart over a greater time range]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `c` in weight callback is a context, not a tick, so it should be `c.tick.major`, not just `c.major`
2. For me it works only if I write callback for whole font, not just font.weight:

```
font: context => {
  if (context.tick && context.tick.major) {
    return {
      weight: 'bold'
    };
  }
}
```

jsFiddle example - https://jsfiddle.net/hrvb0L5y/

example in docs (only in migration guide for some reason) - https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/migration/v3-migration.html

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I knew there must be some simple part of the syntax that I was missing.